# Getting error when calling generic handler in javascript

Tags: handler

```
function callFabricsHandler(type, param, reqType) {
    var ans = null;
    var url = "http://localhost/FabricsShop/fabricsHandler.ashx?reqType=" + reqType + "&" + param;
    $.ajax({       
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: reqType,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            ans = data;
            alert(ans);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
            alert( err+'\n'+jqXHR+'\n'+status);
        }
    });
    return ans;
}
```

Hi, This is my code I am calling a handler from my javascript file ,when I am calling this always getting  following message:

> syntaxerror:Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0 [Object Object]
>   parsererror

This is alert of error part 
Can anyone please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Use fiddler web proxy or some similar software to look at the request and the response.

Comment: while debugging I got readyState=4,Status=200,statusText="ok"

Comment: Not only that I am getting my responseText too

Comment: Well, what is the responseText? Is it valid JSON?

Comment: yes response text is JSON

Comment: Well, show us the response text

Comment: I got the error It was in param it was giving me object and in url object was passing and hence it was giving error now I have a function to convert  param object to string and than I am getting proper response.Now it is working .